# Remember if user is in light/ dark theme

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make it so that if a user clicks toggle light theme it stays light theme throughout all webpages, here is what I have so far.

JS:
    `function toggleLightTheme() { document.body.classList.toggle('light-theme'); }`

HTML:
`<button class="thin" onclick="toggleLightTheme()">Toggle Light Theme</button>`

CSS, light theme: `.light-theme p { color: black; }`(There's more duh.)

CSS, normal: `text-align: center; font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: white;` (There's more duh.)

I attempted to look up some other things but I wasn't smart enough, I do have external CSS and JS files so that you know.

Comment: SO many duplicates of this I suggest you search this site; A few listed of them.  Search for more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dark%2Flight+theme+remember